# Unit-testing IList with CollectionAssert

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mstest, ilist, icollection

The MSTest framework has a CollectionAssert that accepts ICollections.
My method returns an IList. Apparently a list is not a collection..

Are there ways to make my IList an ICollection?

Comment: The connect issue for this. Usual Microsoft response, tsss. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/477870/collectionassert-cannot-be-used-with-hashset-t-and-possibly-other-collections#

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could call the ToArray() extension method on it - Array implements ICollection

Edit: Also, while `List<T>` implements ICollection, `IList<T>` only implements `ICollection<T>` which does not implement ICollection, so if you know the item in the test is a `List<T>`, you should be able to cast it...

Comment: I think IEnumerable for the parameters would have been a better choice. NUnit has got this one right.

Answer (score 1):

You can send in a List

```
    List<string> actual = new List<string>(){"1","2","3"};
    List<string> expected = new List<string>(){"1","2","**EditCaseFalse**"};
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(actual,expected)
```

I get back Failed (third element does not match.)

Comment: and how exactly is this related to the question?

Comment: I send in two list<string> (IList) that are compared in CollectionAssert is that your problem...

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't read in enough on your answer. Please refer @Lee's answer about why this is working but not a solution to my problem.

Comment: I edited your answer to remove a bit of noise so the actual answer is clearer. If you mind, please feel free to roll back.