#  CollectionAssert use with generics?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, generics, mstest

It appears that `CollectionAssert` cannot be used with generics. This is super frustrating; the code I want to test does use generics. What am I to do? Write boilerplate to convert between the two? Manually check collection equivalence?

This fails:

```
ICollection<IDictionary<string, string>> expected = // ...

IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, string>> actual = // ...

// error 1 and 2 here
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected.GetEnumerator().ToList(), actual.ToList());

// error 3 here
Assert.IsTrue(expected.GetEnumerator().SequenceEquals(actual));
```

Compiler errors:

Error 1:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator>' could be found

Error 2

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator>' could be found

Error 3

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator>' does not contain a definition for 'SequenceEquals' and no extension method 'SequenceEquals' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator>' could be found

What am I doing wrong? Am I not using extensions correctly?

**Update:** Ok, this looks a bit better, but still doesn't work:

```
IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, string>> expected = // ...

IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, string>> actual = // ...

CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expected.ToList(), actual.ToList()); // fails
CollectionAssert.IsSubsetOf(expected.ToList(), actual.ToList()); // fails
```

I don't want to be comparing lists; I only care about set membership equality. The order of the members is unimportant. How can I get around this?

Comment: Are you sure? It's been giving me compiler errors, which I will post tomorrow morning.

Comment: I was wrong; CollectionAssert will NOT work on a ICollection<T>. It works with ICollection only. This has been requested on Connect, but so far not implemented. Possible work around: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662458/unittesting-ilist-with-collectionassert

Comment: If I recall correctly, the ICollection and ICollection<T> interfaces are VASTLY different. This is not the case of IEnumerable versus IEnumerable<T>. Please check their methods. ICollection is uses for something OTHER than ICollection<T>. ICollection doesn't even have ADD method - it is used for "more low-level" purposes like multithreading and marshalling. Therefore, I think you should rather find an interface that will suit your needs better, simple IEnumerable maybe?

Comment: "The order of the members is unimportant" - that's exactly what `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` is for. What is the failure message you get with the test? (maybe your expected and actual are not equivalent!)

Comment: It's SequenceEqual, not SequenceEquals, that's probably your compilation error

Comment: 3 should work, this is what I use _Assert.IsTrue(expected.SequenceEqual(actual));_

Comment: Have Microsoft open-sourced this library yet? Can we report and fix it so `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` works with more types?

Answer (score 41):

You **can** use `CollectionAssert` with generic collections. The trick is to understand that the `CollectionAssert` methods operate on `ICollection`, and although few generic collection interfaces implement `ICollection`, `List<T>` does.

Thus, **you can get around this limitation by using the `ToList` extension method:**

```
IEnumerable<Foo> expected = //...
IEnumerable<Foo> actual = //...
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected.ToList(), actual.ToList());
```

That said, I still consider `CollectionAssert` broken in a lot of other ways, so I tend to use `Assert.IsTrue(bool)` with the LINQ extension methods, like this:

```
Assert.IsTrue(expected.SequenceEqual(actual));
```

---

FWIW, I'm currently using these extension methods to perform other comparisons:

```
public static class EnumerableExtension
{
    public static bool IsEquivalentTo(this IEnumerable first, IEnumerable second)
    {
        var secondList = second.Cast<object>().ToList();
        foreach (var item in first)
        {
            var index = secondList.FindIndex(item.Equals);
            if (index < 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            secondList.RemoveAt(index);
        }
        return secondList.Count == 0;
    }

    public static bool IsSubsetOf(this IEnumerable first, IEnumerable second)
    {
        var secondList = second.Cast<object>().ToList();
        foreach (var item in first)
        {
            var index = secondList.FindIndex(item.Equals);
            if (index < 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            secondList.RemoveAt(index);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to import the System.Linq namespace in a using directive. `ToList` is an extension method.

Comment: I added `using System.Linq;` but it still doesn't work:  `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,string>>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,string>>' could be found`

Comment: `ToList` doesn't extend `IEnumerator<T>`, it extends `IEnumerable<T>`. Remove the call to `GetEnumerator()`.

Comment: Right right. Ok, but I still have the problem that this is comparing lists, but I don't care about the order of objects in the collection. I'm just working with sets.

Comment: That would be addressed by CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent, then.

Comment: That fails for me. (See above.)

Comment: SequenceEquals is misspelled; should be SequenceEqual (without the 's')

Answer (score 6):

If you are working with Sets, then use this Idiom

```
HashSet<string> set1  = new HashSet<string>(){"A","B"};
HashSet<string> set2  = new HashSet<string>(){"B","A"};

Assert.IsTrue(set1.SetEquals(set2));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could easily write your own generic version, then move it to a base or utility class that's used in all of your tests. Base it on the LINQ operators like All and Any.